# converting sql with non equi joins to hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm looking for some help in converting a non equi join queries to hive which supports only equi join queries.

I have tried doing the same and would appreciate to know if I got them right else let me know my mistakes and the right way to achieve the same.

a)

```
SELECT 
  a.time_p,
  count(distinct a.consumerid)
from tableA a
join tableB
  on a.consumerid = tableB.consumerid
  and tableB.time_p != a.time_p
group by a.time_p
```

I tried::

```
SELECT time_p as period, count(distinct consumerid) as count
FROM(
SELECT 
  a.time_p,
  a.consumerid,
  CASE
        WHEN tableB.time_p != a.time_p THEN 1
        ELSE null END as testcase
from tableA a
join tableB
  on a.consumerid = tableB.consumerid  
)t WHERE testcase is not null
group by time_p
```

Thanks

Comment: I seriously doubt the logic of that query. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the inequality condition - just not as a join condition:

```
SELECT a.time_p,count(distinct a.consumerid)
from tableA a
join tableB b
ON a.consumerid = b.consumerid
WHERE b.time_p != a.time_p
group by a.time_p;
```

The `WHERE` condition will be applied after the join.

Comment: so in this case the where condition can be used in place of join on condition, are there any scenarios when this does not work..

Comment: I can't think of any scenarios... Note that the `WHERE` condition is enforced after the join - so you could potentially create a large joined table before filtering unneeded rows.